# Access closest child of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an overall 'parent' `div` with several children. In each child there is 1 or 2 grandchildren.

Say I have a variable holding a child, of the 4<sup>th</sup> child. This is the hierarchy:`parent > child4 > secondGrandChild`. (View code below for the names.) I then want to access the closest previous `secondGrandChild` to it.

So basically it should go to `child3`, check if it has `secondGrandChild` in it. If it does, great, if not it should go to the previous one and do the same check.

Here's what I tried, but it said it didn't exist:

```
console.log($('#grandChild4').parent().closest('.chlid > secondGrandChild').offset().left);
```

Here's the hierarchy: (Note, not every child will have `secondGrandChild`.)

```
<div class- "parent">
    <div class="child" id="child1">
        <div class="firstGrandChild"></div>
        <div class="secondGrandChild" id="grandChild1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child" id="child2">
        <div class="firstGrandChild"></div>
        <div class="secondGrandChild" id="grandChild2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child" id="child3">
        <div class="firstGrandChild"></div>
        <!-- <div class="secondGrandChild" id="grandChild3"></div> -->
    </div>
    <div class="child" id="child4">
        <div class="firstGrandChild"></div>
        <div class="secondGrandChild" id="grandChild4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child" id="child5">
        <div class="firstGrandChild"></div>
        <div class="secondGrandChild" id="grandChild5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Syntax error at `class- "parent"` ? , missing `.` at `.closest('.chlid > secondGrandChild')` ?

Comment: Just tried it, and it says the same thing.

Comment: You do have a spelling mistake in your JavaScript. `.chlid` rather than `.child`. May that is causing you the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this,

```
var $secondGrandChilds = $('.child > .secondGrandChild');
var currentIndex = $secondGrandChilds.index($('#grandChild4'));
var item = $secondGrandChilds.get(currentIndex-1);

console.log($(item).offset().left);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k9gu16v6/1/

**Edit**

Or better,

```
var $item = $('#grandChild4').parent()
                             .prevAll('.child')
                             .find('.secondGrandChild')
                             .last()

console.log($item.offset().left);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k9gu16v6/3/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `.parent()` and `.prev()` and `.children()` like so:

```
var start =  $('#grandChild4').parent();
while( start.prev('.child').length && !start.prev().children('.secondGrandChild').length ) {
    start = start.prev('.child');
}
if( start.prev('.child').length ) {
    console.log( start.prev().children('.secondGrandChild').offset().left );
}
```

```js
    var start =  $('#grandChild4').parent();
    while( start.prev('.child').length && !start.prev().children('.secondGrandChild').length ) {
        start = start.prev('.child');
    }
    if( start.prev('.child').length ) {
        console.log( start.prev().children('.secondGrandChild').offset().left );
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" id="child1">
        <div class="firstGrandChild"></div>
        <div class="secondGrandChild" id="grandChild1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child" id="child2">
        <div class="firstGrandChild"></div>
        <div class="secondGrandChild" id="grandChild2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child" id="child3">
        <div class="firstGrandChild"></div>
        <!--div class="secondGrandChild" id="grandChild3"></div-->
    </div>
    <div class="child" id="child4">
        <div class="firstGrandChild"></div>
        <div class="secondGrandChild" id="grandChild4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child" id="child5">
        <div class="firstGrandChild"></div>
        <div class="secondGrandChild" id="grandChild5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The error? Perhaps it's because you have the target element commented out. Uncomment it and it should work fine. **Gives the value 8 in the included demo.**

Comment: I wrote at the first line of the question: "In each child there is 1 **or 2** grandchildren."

Comment: So why are you trying to get the offset of a nonexistent element?

Comment: No. If it doesn't exist, it should go the the previous one.

Comment: So why change the rules when the game is underway?

Comment: I'm not, I wrote that in the question too. The third paragraph: "If it does, great, if not it should go to the previous one and do the same check."

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error at `html` at `<div class- "parent"` ? ; no `.chlid` element appear to exist within document ; missing `.` at `.closest('.chlid > secondGrandChild')` , try substituting `.child` for `.chlid` at selector

Try correcting syntax errors , using `.cloest()` , `.siblings()` , `.index()` , `eq()` , `.find()`

```js
var child = $("#grandChild4"), elem = ".child", el = ".secondGrandChild";
console.log(
          child 
          // closes `.child`
          .closest(elem)
          // filter siblings to return `.child` 
          // at index before `elem` in `.child` collection
          .siblings(elem).eq(child.index(elem) - 1)
          // find `elem` : `".secondGrandChild"`
          .find(el)
          .offset().left
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" id="child1">
        <div class="firstGrandChild"></div>
        <div class="secondGrandChild" id="grandChild1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child" id="child2">
        <div class="firstGrandChild"></div>
        <div class="secondGrandChild" id="grandChild2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child" id="child3">
        <div class="firstGrandChild"></div>
        <div class="secondGrandChild" id="grandChild3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child" id="child4">
        <div class="firstGrandChild"></div>
        <div class="secondGrandChild" id="grandChild4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child" id="child5">
        <div class="firstGrandChild"></div>
        <div class="secondGrandChild" id="grandChild5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```